# How to send JSON data from PHP corectly?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get JSON from PHP using jQuery's $.getJSON function to fill up a table. On the PHP side I use echo json_encode. It works correctly, the table gets filled up but the representation of the array can also be seen on top of the site like this:

"[{"id":"1","0":"1","author":"Tolkien","1":"Tolkien","title":"Gyuruk Ura","2":"Gyuruk Ura","isbn":"8759","3":"8759"},{"id":"2","0":"2","author":"Tolkien","1":"Tolkien","title":"Hobbit","2":"Hobbit","isbn":"8759","3":"8759"}]"

jQuery Code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            let books = "";
            $.getJSON( "ViewBookstore.php", function( data ) {
                $.each( data, function( index, value ) {
                    books += "<tr>";
                    books += "<td>"+value.author+"</td>";
                    books += "<td>"+value.title+"</td>";
                    books += "<td>"+value.isbn+"</td>";
                    books += '<td>' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-info" id="edit">Edit</button>' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>' +
                        '</td>';
                    books += "</tr>";
                });
                $("#books-table").append(books);
            });
        });
</script>
```

My PHP Code:

```
 class ViewBookstore extends ControllerBookstore
{
 public function showAllBooks(){
        echo json_encode($this->getAllBooks());
    }
}

$view = new ViewBookstore();
$view->showAllBooks();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your jquery code is in ViewBookstore.php? so your php code is running and show that result on top of your page. for preventing that you can have some control statements like this:

> it's very simple example

change

```
$.getJSON( "ViewBookstore.php", function( data ) {
```

to

```
$.getJSON( "ViewBookstore.php?show_books=true", function( data ) {
```

and in your ViewBookstore.php change

```
$view = new ViewBookstore();
$view->showAllBooks();
```

with

```
if(!empty($_GET['show_books']))
{
    $view = new ViewBookstore();
    $view->showAllBooks();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this was the solution. :)